# Malformed Query Error - Aggregate query not allowed with this api version

Tags: javascript, salesforce, soql

I created a custom javascript button in developer environment that has the below function to determine the amount of products attached to the Opportunity with a specific Product Name.  I am getting a malformed query error from this function:

```
function getProductTypes (oppId) { 
var result = sforce.connection.query("Select COUNT(Id) prodCount From OpportunityLineItem where OpportunityId = '" + oppId + "' and PricebookEntry.Product2.Name IN ('EAP') "); 
var count = result.records.prodCount; 
return count; 
}
```

What I don't understand is that in my salesforce developer environment, this button works 100% but when I went to install this into a client's developer sandbox, it gave me the malformed query error: Aggregate query not allowed with this api version.  Is there a setting that I need to change in their dev environment or is there something really wrong with my code?

Thanks!

Rachel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the version number in your `{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/(here!)/connection.js")}`.

Probably it's something ancient like "13" they still have [in the docs](http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_functions_i_z.htm).

There's also non-zero chance that this function tries to be smart and doesn't include the connection.js if one of previous buttons has used it. Check the custom JS buttons that load before yours on your client's page layout and bump them all up?

Comment: I'm using version 24: {!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/24.0/connection.js")}  I will also ask my client to see if they have any buttons that use that a lower version to see if that may be breaking it.

Comment: Your side should be OK, `COUNT()` is in since v.18: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_agg_functions.htm

Comment: Eh, I forgot about one more thing. They can have Javascript (and thus - connection.js) injected in some other places like sidebar. Sidebar is rendered before the actual "main" content we control so it'd also impact the buttons. Would be best for your client to just examine the page's source HTML to track it...

Comment: That was it!  There was javascript in the sidebar causing the issue.  Thanks!

Comment: Thx for coming back and accepting, mystery solved :)